# laravel 5.7 console test how to create Artisan::command()

Tags: laravel

Hi Where to put this code ,it must be something like class or maybe I will have to generate file and how to do it ?

```
Artisan::command('question', function () {
    $name = $this->ask('What is your name?');

    $language = $this->choice('Which language do you program in?', [
        'PHP',
        'Ruby',
        'Python',
    ]);

    $this->line('Your name is '.$name.' and you program in '.$language.'.');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options.

**First option:** In console routing file (routes/console.php)

```
Artisan::command('question', function () { 

    $name = $this->ask('What is your name?');

    $language = $this->choice('Which language do you program in?', [
        'PHP',
        'Ruby',
        'Python',
    ]);

    $this->line('Your name is '.$name.' and you program in '.$language.'.');

});
```

**Second option:** create command class

```
php artisan make:command QuestionCommand
```

And place logic in `handle()` method:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class QuestionCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'question';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $name = $this->ask('What is your name?');

        $language = $this->choice('Which language do you program in?', [
            'PHP',
            'Ruby',
            'Python',
        ]);

        $this->line('Your name is '.$name.' and you program in '.$language.'.');
    }
}
```